# Where am I messing up my if , else if , else ? New to Java

Tags: java

I cannot figure out the `if`, `else if` and `else` structure for this question.

So if `cert = y`, then it should print out and stop. But if `cert = n` then it should ask one more question and then give a `true/false` from that.

This error code is what I cannot get around in it.

> error: variable course might not have been initialized

My code:

```
System.out.print("Did you receive at least a D grade in pass Irish in the Leaving Cert < y or n > ");
cert = input.next().charAt(0);

if ((age > 18 && age < 35) && (weight < 100) && (record == 'n') && (cert == 'y')
        && ((gender == 'm') && (height >= 1.85) || (gender == 'f') && (height >= 1.60))) {
    System.out.println("Congrats you are eligible to join the nGardai");
} else if (cert == 'n') {
    System.out.print("Do you commit to a 10 week Irish course on application < y or n > ");
    course = input.next().charAt(0);
}
if (((age > 18 && age < 35) && (weight < 100) && (record == 'n') && (course == 'y')
        && ((gender == 'm') && (height >= 1.85) || (gender == 'f') && (height >= 1.60)))) {
    System.out.println("Congrats you are eligible to join the nGardai");
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry");
}
```

Comment: initialized your course variable course = "";

Comment: Try to write a simple program to understand if-else structure.

Comment: Do you declare `course` anywhere before this?  In your final `if` statement you have `(course == 'y')`.  If `course` hasn't been declared previously then this will cause the error code.

Comment: First, pretty printing is the least effort you can make. Second, [mvce] is a requirement here. Third, the message is self explanatory, compiler cannot ensure that your variable is always initialized. Can't you see why? (Take the first alternative).

Comment: Sorry guys I'm new to Stackoverflow so wasn't sure how to really ask the question properly. ManojBanik I have done before but nothing like this @Martin I thought where I have it would initialise it because it is before the next if? Finally, I don't know what a [mvce] is so that isn't the intended purpose of this exercise.

Comment: No problem, follow the suggestions what others already said, if the problem remains - ask in a new comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You end the first `else`right before the second `if` while it should be nested. Remember the second if should be checked **if the first one is false**

A proper code indentation could help to solve those easy-to-fix errors.

```
if ((age > 18 && age < 35) && (weight < 100) && (record == 'n') && (cert == 'y') && ((gender == 'm') && (height >= 1.85) || (gender == 'f') && (height >= 1.60)))        
{
    System.out.println("Congrats you are eligible to join the nGardai");
} else if (cert == 'n') {
    System.out.print("Do you commit to a 10 week Irish course on application < y or n > ");
    course = input.next().charAt(0);

    if (((age > 18 && age < 35) && (weight < 100) && (record == 'n') && (course == 'y') && ((gender == 'm') && (height >= 1.85) || (gender == 'f') && (height >= 1.60))))         
    {
        System.out.println("Congrats you are eligible to join the nGardai");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, okay now I get it. Things like this are tedious to me and I was hammering out all sorts of attempts. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your code, you declare a variable named "count" but didn't initialize it, yet you're trying to compare it with some value

> course == 'y'

The compiler is clever and complains, that if your;

```
else if (cert == 'n') {
System.out.print("Do you commit to a 10 week Irish course on application < y or n > ");
course = input.next().charAt(0);
}
```

block doesn't not execute, the "count" variable will never be initialized, and you cannot do a comparison with that variable.